# Postgis - How to detect an instersection of the bigger area instersected

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have two maps loaded into the database, one map has the geometry of the states, and the other one has the geometry of the urban areas.
I want to make and intersection to make a relation between the urban areas and the states to know which urban area belong to each state.

The problem is that some urban areas occupy two states, the urban area belongs to the state in which it has more area within the state geometry.

i could use  the command `ST_Intersects`, but it would add it both states in which the urban are instersect with the states.

What sql command i have to use? i have read the documentation of 
`ST_CoveredBy` and `ST_Within`  but i'm not really sure if they work for what i need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First create the instersection object between state and urban region and calculate area size, using the `ST_intersect` on the `JOIN` will use index to avoid overhead.
- Then assign a `row_number` to each `urban_id` order by area size.
- With `rn = 1` mean only return the largest area for each urban_id.

.

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT S.state_id, 
           U.urban_id, 
           ST_Area(ST_Intersection( S.geom, U.geom )) a_geom 
                 -- This create the intersect geom and calculate area
    FROM states S
    JOIN urban U
      ON ST_Intersects( S.geom, U.geom ) -- This is a boolean function
),
area as (
    SELECT state_id, 
           urban_id,                
           row_number() over (partition by urban_id order by a_geom desc) as rn
    FROM  cte
)
SELECT state_id,
       urban_id
FROM area
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ST_Area` on `ST_Intersection` to sort and `LATERAL JOIN`.

```
WITH states(id, geom) AS(
    VALUES  (1, ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0)')))
        ,(2, ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 0, 2 0, 2 1, 1 1, 1 0)')))
),cities(id, geom) AS(
    VALUES  (1,ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0.5 0.5)'), 0.3))
        ,(2,ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1.5 0.5)'), 0.3))
        ,(3,ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1.1 0.5)'), 0.3))
)
SELECT c.id AS city, s.id AS state
FROM cities AS c
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL  (SELECT s.id, s.geom
                 FROM states AS s
                 WHERE ST_Intersects(s.geom, c.geom)
                 ORDER BY ST_AREA(ST_Intersection(s.geom,c.geom)) DESC
                 LIMIT 1) AS s
```